# My website is not working after i deleted and replaced it a part of the database in flask-sqlalchemy (sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError)

Tags: python, sqlite

So I was following this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI so the whole code is there and everything was working out perfectly until I accidentally deleted part of the database from the file database.db

```
SQLite format3
� _ �_ �YtablenotenoteCREATE TABLE note (
id INTEGER NOT NULL,  
data VARCHAR(10000), 
date DATETIME, 
user_id INTEGER, 
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user (id)    
)�/�AtableuseruserCREATE TABLE user (  
id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
email VARCHAR(150), 
password VARCHAR(150), 
first_name VARCHAR(150), 
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
UNIQUE (email)
)'; indexsqlite_autoindex_user_1user
```

So the code above is the original database.db code
and I deleted the code below and immediately replaced it

```
id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
data VARCHAR(10000), 
date DATETIME, 
user_id INTEGER, 
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user (id)
```

but when the code was deleted the website wouldn't run anymore and I would start to get this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (sqlite3.DatabaseError) database disk
> image is malformed [SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.email AS
> user_email, user.password AS user_password, user.first_name AS
> user_first_name  FROM user  WHERE user.id = ?] [parameters: (1,)]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)

Comment: It looks as if you have replaced the binary sqlite file with a textfile?  Rename or delete the database file and recreate it with `db.create_all()`.

Comment: I tried deleting it and renaming it and creating a new one but im getting the same error

Comment: The only way you can be getting the same error is if you have replaced the file again.  Please provide a [mre] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite database stored in binary format, not just as some text. So that's why your database is now corrupted and not working

To work with existing database look at [DB Browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org) or [sqlite3 CLI](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) instead of text editor

To solve an error, restore old database and replace malformed one, or just create new one.